# What could cause these lengthy/failing pings every ~10 seconds?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, mac, dns

Pings from my computer get really long every ~10 seconds, sometimes timing out. Here's a ping log from just now:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=120 time=12.094 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=13.717 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=11.962 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=120 time=927.768 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=120 time=1128.735 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=120 time=863.108 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=120 time=1067.987 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=120 time=67.417 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=120 time=12.045 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=120 time=12.021 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=120 time=12.010 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=120 time=13.770 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=120 time=11.906 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=120 time=956.193 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=120 time=1151.187 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=15 ttl=120 time=884.695 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=16 ttl=120 time=879.668 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=17 ttl=120 time=11.026 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=18 ttl=120 time=82.937 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=19 ttl=120 time=13.104 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=20 ttl=120 time=12.057 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=21 ttl=120 time=12.168 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=22 ttl=120 time=13.145 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23 ttl=120 time=993.377 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=24 ttl=120 time=1192.837 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=25 ttl=120 time=924.561 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=26 ttl=120 time=913.632 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=27 ttl=120 time=11.092 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=28 ttl=120 time=12.865 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=29 ttl=120 time=103.837 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=30 ttl=120 time=13.205 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=31 ttl=120 time=11.973 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=32 ttl=120 time=13.748 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=33 ttl=120 time=528.284 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=34 ttl=120 time=583.403 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=35 ttl=120 time=984.983 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=36 ttl=120 time=981.329 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=37 ttl=120 time=12.047 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=38 ttl=120 time=14.448 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
39 packets transmitted, 39 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 11.026/396.573/1192.837/462.990 ms
```

I saw no such thing when I:

- Ethernet directly into the WiFi router
- Ping from my Android phone, using the same WiFi network

I'm using a 2015 MacBook Pro. I'd love to figure out what's causing this, but am unsure how to find out. Thoughts?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** Here's the output of `sudo mtr 8.8.8.8` over 60 seconds.

- US Internet is my ISP
- Zyxel is the manufacturer of my WiFi router, which was provided by US Internet

```
MacBook-Pro.local (192.168.1.60)                             2019-03-10T12:26:40-0500
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                             Packets               Pings
 Host                                      Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. emg3425-q10a.zyxel.com                  3.3%    61    2.6 174.5   2.5 1179. 304.5
 2. 50-93-254-1.fttp.usinternet.com        18.6%    60    3.5 179.3   3.3 1305. 337.8
 3. fs006r002-mpls.usinternet.com          15.3%    60    3.0 178.5   2.9 1125. 311.0
 4. v103.usi-cr04-mpls.usinternet.com      16.9%    60    3.0 164.4   2.7 1008. 266.2
 5. po12.usi-cr01-chi1.usinternet.com      16.9%    60   11.9 277.9  10.6 1311. 414.8
 6. eqix-ch-100g.google.com                16.9%    60   11.1 290.9  10.9 1421. 424.7
 7. 108.170.243.174                        18.6%    60   12.0 298.7  11.7 1367. 424.6
 8. 209.85.142.205                         18.6%    60   11.2 306.7  10.8 1362. 440.8
 9. google-public-dns-a.google.com         16.9%    60   12.0 299.2  11.0 1475. 458.8
```

Comment: If you are on a Mac, install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) (if you don’t have it installed already) and then install [MTR (My Traceroute)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)) like this: `brew install mtr`. With that installed run `sudo mtr 8.8.8.8` and it will show you the trace route and ping response time in context allowing you to determine what the bottleneck might be.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a really neat tool. However, I'm not sure how to read it. I'll update my answer with the output.

Comment: Priblem is clearly related to WIFI (notjing to do with DNS). Most likely noise in the 2.4 gig +or 5 gig) spectrum. Its difficult to solve asnnot all noise comes from wifi devices - it could be machinary or even a neighbour playing with an IOT board.

Comment: Try getting something like WIFI analyzer (for Android) and see.if it gives you any hints - particularly try alternative channels - and if possible using the 5 gig band.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin It’s easy to understand: There is a tool called `ping` which pings and a tool called `traceroute`. One pings a remote server. The other traces the route to a remote server. What MTR does is combine these two tools into one. So it will trace the route (showing all hoops) to a remote server and then will show you the ping response time on each hop. In this case if you run `sudo mtr 8.8.8.8` you can see what the bottle-neck is by looking at the list of items and see which is the slowest.

Comment: Agree with @davidgo, although sources of noise that are not from wifi devices will not show up. If that zytel is relatively new you may be able to fidget with the 802.11h settings. (It should be on by default) not always though... The lag may be it switching channels when it detects airport radar or satellites. Check it's logs, if that's the case you should see warnings about it in the log.

Comment: @JakeGould See my above edit, which shows the output of `mtr`. Is there anything that's standing out to you? It all looks pretty even to me.

Comment: Looks good. So I would guess this is a Wi-Fi problem more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This is often caused by something causing your radio to go off-channel to scan for Wi-Fi networks periodically.

Common causes:

- If you're at the edge of your AP's range, your client will do "roam scans" looking for other APs publushing the same network name but with higher signal strength so the client can roam to it.
- Something overusing the Location Services APIs, causing scans for Wi-Fi-based geolocation.
- Running some kind of Wi-Fi network scanning tool, such iStumbler or some Dashboard widget.